# Localizing methods for jQuery append prepend wrap parent

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript, wp-localize-script

So I am serializing some options in WordPress and then localizing them to be used in my jQuery script, however what I am trying to do next isn't working.

```
jQuery('.advert')+ lu_ban_object.method +('<div>Hello World</div>')
```

So in my db I've got some values serialized; following is the data that is being localized to used as method chosen by the user

> s:6:"method";s:5:".wrap";}

Essentially what it should do is;

```
jQuery('.advert').wrap('<div>Hello World</div>')
```

The user can also append, prepend, wrap, etc but it is just not working, the methods are being localized and serialized so it should work, but it isnt. I have tried the following as well;

```
jQuery('.advert')lu_ban_object.method('<div>Hello World</div>')
jQuery('.advert')jQuery(lu_ban_object.method)('<div>Hello World</div>')
```

Is just not working.... anyone know how to solve this. or am I doing it the wrong way? I just have a list in the settings page and each has a value for a different method such as;

```
<select name="lu_ban_data[method]" id="lu_ban_data" />
        <option value=".append">Append</option>
        <option value=".prepend">Prepend</option>
        <option value=".wrap">Wrap</option>
        <option value=".parent().parent().wrap">Parent</option>
```

**update: var dump**

```
array (size=4)
  'title' => string 'My custom title' (length=15)
  'msg' => string 'My message' (length=10)
  'image' => string 'http://i.imgur.com/3tPjx4l.png' (length=30)
  'method' => string '.prepend' (length=8)
```

I tried the bracket solution but still nothing, `jQuery('.advert')[lu_ban_object.method]("<div>Hello World</div>")` I am getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '.prepend'` So I added the plus symbols and the message went away but the div was still not being added to the page `+[lu_ban_object.method]+`

following is my localized data that is being printed in the header

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var lu_ban_object = {"title":"My custom title","msg":"My message","image":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/3tPjx4l.png","method":".prepend"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lu_ban_object.method` equals the string `wrap`, and you'd like to use that string to call jQuery's `wrap()` method, you'd use bracket notation :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.advert')[lu_ban_object.method]('<div>Hello World</div>');
});
```

Comment: i didn't know about the bracket notation. thnx! +1